# Asp MenuBar selected tab

Tags: asp.net, html, css

I have a little problem with my site.
I never used Asp.net so paste directly the correct code if you can.
I have insert in my master page the menubar with this code

```
        <div id="cssmenu">
        <ul>

          <li><a href="/IT/Default.aspx">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="/IT/come_raggiungerci.aspx">Dove Siamo</a></li>
            <li><a href="/IT/contatti.aspx">Contatti</a></li>
            <li><a href="/IT/servizi.aspx">I Nostri Servizi</a></li>

        </ul>
    </div>
```

How can i show in which tab you are?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the Page.Title attribute from the page to set an title and build an switch in the master pages's code behind which will check on Page.Title
And if you hit tine correct title you could set an attribute

**in the page**

```
<%@ Page Title="Aanbod" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Voorraad.aspx.cs" Inherits="AutoVanNetten.Vooraad" %>
```

**in the master page code behind**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        switch (Page.Title)
        {
            case "Home":
                HomeButton.Attributes.Add("class", "active");
                break;
            case "Aanbod":
                VooraadButton.Attributes.Add("class", "active");
                break;
            case "Contact":
                ContactButton.Attributes.Add("class", "active");
                break;
          case "Diensten":
                DienstenButton.Attributes.Add("class", "active");
                break;
          case "Over":
                OverButton.Attributes.Add("class", "active");
                break;
            default:
                VooraadButton.Attributes.Add("class", "active");
                break;
        }
    }
```

**menu in the master page**

```
 <ul class="nav">
    <li runat="server" ID="HomeButton"><a href="/">HOME</a></li>
    <li runat="server" ID="VooraadButton"><a href="/Voorraad">AANBOD</a></li>
    <li runat="server" ID="DienstenButton"><a href="/Diensten">DIENSTEN</a></li>
    <li runat="server" ID="OverButton"><a href="/Over">OVER ONS</a></li>
    <li runat="server" ID="ContactButton"><a href="/Contact">CONTACT</a></li>
  </ul>
```

This is the exact code of how i use it on one of my sites